# Applications installed on another hard disk

Tags: windows, hard-drive

Here is my setup: I have three hard disks, one for Windows 10 (SSD, C:), one for my documents (HDD, D:) and another HDD for my applications (F:, ranging from Microsoft office to Steam games, FTP clients ...)

I want to reinstall windows, so I am going to format my SSD and install a clean Windows 10.

Is there any way I can mount D:\ to "my documents" and F:\ to "Program Files" as if these applications have been installed in the "new" Windows using the installer , and can I keep these applications' preferences & data from the "old" Windows ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(IMPORTANT: read the second half!)

> Is there any way I can mount D:\ to "my documents" and F:\ to "Program Files"

Yes, that is possible. Go to "Disk Management" (search for "Computer Management" in start menu, it is in there). Right-click the drive (technically I should say "partition") you want to mount and choose "Change Drive Letter and Paths..."

[image: Change Drive Letter and Paths]

After that click the Add-button and in the window that pops up you can select a path to mount it on:

[image: Mount to path]

Optionally you can remove the drive-letter, since you don't really need it any more.

---

Having said all this: I am not so sure it is a smart idea to do this. Maybe if you did this from the very beginning, but now there is both data on that drive and in the "My Documents"/"Program Files" folder and the drive. No matter what you do, if you (re)install windows, there will always be data there. And as you can see in the latest screenshot, the folder you want to mount to HAS to be empty (makes sense right?)

So I suggest just not doing it and just whenever you install a program install it in your other drive (at least, that's what I'm doing) that way I can also choose to install a program on my SSD if I want to (for some programs/games it gains quite a bit of performance, and I didn't buy an SSD to put absolutely nothing on it ^^)

And for "My Documents": I know there is a way to tell windows to use an other location for that, I don't know how to do it off the top of my head, but I know for sure that is possible. (If not I have a reaaaly weird memory....)

P.S. don't mind me having windows classic theme

Answer (score 0):

Any application that you install will have to be installed again. If you install it to a different location in the new windows, that does not matter.

Make sure you backup your profile entirely, including the AppData folder. This'll be where most of your settings are.

Do note that if you want, you can `reset windows` to a fresh state, and choose to keep your files. This will ensure that everything you need to backup will be moved to a folder windows old.

To do this, open start and search for `Refresh Windows`.

Answer (score 0):

When you format the Windows partition, you'll lose the registry.  Missing registry entries will render most applications unusable -- there's actually a term for programs that work anyway, *xcopy install*.  In addition to COM registrations, many user preferences are stored in the registry.

You can attempt to export parts of the registry and restore them to the new system, but that defeats the purpose of having a clean Windows install, and the only reliable way to preserve registry content is to do an upgrade (not clean) install anyway.